# Using Reflection with Ninject

Tags: ninject

In the following piece of code I used Reflection directly to determ every class(located in "..binaries\plugins") that implements Iplugin,so I can bind those classes with Ninject.My question is if there is a way of doing the same using Ninject only?.If someone knows how to do it with Linfu I will appreciate it too.

```
private void BindDlls(StandardKernel standardKernel)
    {   
        var pluginsDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\plugins";
        var plgDir = new DirectoryInfo(pluginsDirectory);
        var files = plgDir.GetFiles("*.dll");

        foreach (var pluginFileInfo in files)
        {
            var pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(pluginFileInfo.FullName);
            var pluginFileTypes = pluginAssembly.GetTypes();

            foreach (var pluginFileType in pluginFileTypes)
            {
                if (pluginFileType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IPlugin)) && !pluginFileType.IsAbstract)
                {
                    standardKernel.Bind<IPlugin>().To(pluginFileType);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the conventions extension, but be sure to use the 3.0 RC3 pre-release.

On [GitHub](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/)

On [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/ninject.extensions.conventions/2.2.0.5)

Be sure to look at the [**integration tests**](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/tree/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Test/IntegrationTests) for example usage.